# ¿Cómo evitar el acceso sin haberse logueado?

Tags: javascript, html, api, axios

necesito un poco de ayuda, estoy trabajando en un login el cual consumo de un web services, estoy buscando información o un ejemplo para evitar el acceso a los otros form sin antes haberse logueado, ya que si se pone la URL de los otros form ingresa y muestra la información.

```
       var usuario = localStorage.getItem("usuario");
       const url = 'http://localhost/api/AppWeb/Login_User';
       var getData = function() {
       var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
       var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
       axios({
       method: 'POST',
       url: url,
       data: {
            usuario: usuario,
            pass: pass
        }
       }).then(res => {

        if (res.status == 200) {
            if (res.data.rol == 2) {
                console.log(res.data.rol)
                console.log(usuario);
                localStorage.setItem("usuario", usuario);
                location.href = "sistema/inicioUsu.php";
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem("usuario", usuario);
                location.href = "sistema/inicio.php";
            }

        } else
        if (res.status == 404) {
            alert("cointraseña incorrecta");
        }
        console.log(res.status);
        })
         .catch(err =>
        alert("No quedó")
        )
        }
```

Comment: Tienes que autentificar al usuario desde el servidor, cualquier persona que acceda  `/Login_User` puede ver el código de html y entrar manualmente desde su explorador a la ruta `sistema/inicioUsu.php` o `sistema/inicio.php`

Comment: Todo lo que ocupo con js lo tengo bloqueado, nadie puede entrar a esas carpetas.

Comment: Entonces no te pude entender. ¿A qué te refieres con *ya que si se pone la URL de los otros form ingresa y muestra la información*?

Comment: Mira esta URL http://localhost/Res/LaudemAVE/index.html es para el login y una vez que inicies sesión te debe mandar a http://localhost/Res/LaudemAVE/sistema/inicio.php, pero, si se pone esa URL, en el navegador si me redirige sin antes haber iniciado sesión.

Comment: Exacto, a eso me refería en el primer comentario, con solo ver tu código supuse que puedo hacer eso con tu sitio. Toda persona que acceda a la página puede ver el código HTML y ver que tu manera de impedir acceso a X ruta consiste en tratar de esconder la ruta de acceso. Pero eso es imposible porque está en tú código. El que debe de decidir si brinda o no la página al usuario para la ruta `localhost/Res/LaudemAVE/sistema/inicio.php` es el servidor.

Comment: Aaa bueno, puse eso, para que se tomara como referencia el como esta mi inicio de sesión y ver si se puede crear alguna variable de sesión con web services

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es que el usuario se autentifique (tal y como has hecho) y que el servidor responda con algún token, como por ejemplo un jwt y lo guardas en el explorador web del usuario. Luego cuándo la persona quiera acceder a una ruta que necesita autentificación que presente el token con el request para poder ver la página, el servidor verifica el token y luego decide si devolverle la página de la ruta, o una página que diga que no está autentificado.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, me podrás apoyar con algún ejemplo o articulo de como guardar el token por favor

Comment: ¿Cómo estás implementando tu servidor?

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no es relevante si el código HTML, CSS y JS está disponible públicamente.

Lo que se debe restringir, en la mayoría de los casos, es el acceso a la base de datos, o archivos del servidor.

Esto se logra normalmente con algún tipo de función criptográfica. Por ejemplo, si hay un recurso en tu servidor que sólo se puede cambiar por determinadas personas, lo ideal es que estas personas presenten algún tipo de credenciales (Usuario/contraseña, huella digital, código de verificación etc.)

De este modo no importa si un atacante gana acceso a los archivos públicos (HTML, CSS, JS), porque los recursos privados están protegidos.

Habiendo dicho esto, es pertinente hacer validaciones para que en la interfaz del usuario sólo se muestren los recursos a los que tiene acceso el usuario que está interactuando con la interfaz.

Ejemplo: Si hay un botón que permita borrar usuarios, sólo mostrarlo a los administradores que ya hayan iniciado sesión.

Comment: Mira esta URL localhost/Res/LaudemAVE/index.html es para el login y una vez que inicies sesión te debe mandar a localhost/Res/LaudemAVE/sistema/inicio.php, pero, si se pone esa URL, en el navegador si me redirige sin antes haber iniciado sesión.